# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException - Selenium Test

Tags: java, selenium

In Java, I have written a Selenium test for testing Yahoo Movies. I am testing [This Movie](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/finding-dory-trailer-202300942.html) from yahoo website. But the code that I have written (given below) is throws an Exception (given below). I am new to Selenium, so please solve the problem.

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



public class Tests {

    WebDriver driver;
    Wait<WebDriver> wait;
    boolean result;

    Tests() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        boolean result = new Tests().movies();
        System.out.println(result?"PASSED":"FAILED");
    }

    public boolean movies() {
        try {
            System.out.print("Testing Movies... ");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Movies")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Finding Dory")).click();
            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                    return webDriver.findElement(By.className("yvp-flash-video")) != null;
                }
            });
            return driver.findElement(By.id("Main")).getText().contains("'Finding Dory' Trailer");
        }
        catch(Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Testing Movies... org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Finding Dory"}
Command duration or timeout: 5.08 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Jahanzeb', ip: '10.99.14.207', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Finding Dory}
Session ID: 5f14f1fa-85e4-471e-982f-27317dd766b7
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=46.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at Tests.movies(Tests.java:189)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Finding Dory"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Jahanzeb', ip: '10.99.14.207', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/JAHANZ~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous903980554428331931webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/JAHANZ~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous903980554428331931webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/JAHANZ~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous903980554428331931webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/JAHANZ~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous903980554428331931webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/JAHANZ~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous903980554428331931webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assumming that you are trying to click a "link" named "Finding Dory" on this page:
[image]

But **this is not a link** - try to click it manually, it simply is not possible to click on it.
If you click on it, nothing happens, it's just not clickeable 
- this is nothing but a simple text "Finding Dory".
What you can do is to click a link named "Play trailer" that is located below the text "Finding Dory". 
The problem is that there are many links with the same name "Play trailer" on this page, and WebDriver doesn't know which link should be clicked, and returns an error if you try a simple method `findElement( By.linkText('Play trailer')).click();`
You need to tell WebDriver that it should click on the link that is located under the text "Finding Dory". To do it you need more advanced locating strategies than a simle method `By.linkText`. The two the most popular are locating using xpath or css expressions.
First you need to examine a structure of this page. Open this page in the browser, and press F12 key - this opens Developer Tools window (how to use this tool is beyond this answer). You will see something like this:
[image]

---

That is:

- `DIV` tag that contains a text "Finding Dory"
- followed by `A` tag that contains a text "Play trailer"

You can build an xpath expression for the above, that finds a link "Play trailer" located under a `DIV` tag that contains "Finding Dory" in this way :

```
//div[contains(.,'Finding Dory')]/following-sibling::a[contains(.,'Play trailer')]
```

and then replace this line of your code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Finding Dory")).click();
```

with this one:

```
driver.findElement(
   By.xpath(
     "//div[contains(.,'Finding Dory')]/following-sibling::a[contains(.,'Play trailer')]"
)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//a[contains(text(),'Finding Dory'))].click();

Note: If "Finding Dory" is having any link then only the above code will work.